# RDS cloudwatch metric "Free Storage Space" does not free up with drop table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS Postgress 11 RDS instance in which I've performed a drop table on a large table. However, the space savings is not observed in the AWS RDS console graph - "Free storage space", this remains the same. However, querying pg_database_size does indeed show the space savings. Why is this?

Comment: Ask AWS support.

Comment: i noticed a spike in free disk space still not what i was expecting today. it seemed to have taken 5 hours to even show up. curious if this frees up with more time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run a full vacuum? From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html):

> Plain VACUUM (without FULL) simply reclaims space and makes it available for re-use.
>
> ...
>
> However, extra space is not returned to the operating system (in most cases); it's just kept available for re-use within the same table.
>
> ...
>
> VACUUM FULL rewrites the entire contents of the table into a new disk file
> with no extra space, allowing unused space to be returned to the operating system.
>
> ...